# Concatenate string instead of just replacing it

Tags: postgresql, insert, sql-update, insert-update, upsert

I have a table with standard columns where I want to perform regular `INSERT`s.

But one of the columns is of type `varchar` with special semantics. It's a string that's supposed to behave as a [set](https://byjus.com/maths/sets/) of strings, where the elements of the set are separated by commas.

Eg. if one row has in that `varchar` column the value `fish,sheep,dove`, and I insert the string `,fish,eagle`, I want the result to be `fish,sheep,dove,eagle` (ie. `eagle` gets added to the set, but `fish` doesn't because it's already in the set).

I have here this `Postgres` code that does the "set concatenation" that I want:

```
SELECT string_agg(unnest, ',') AS x FROM (SELECT DISTINCT unnest(string_to_array('fish,sheep,dove' || ',fish,eagle', ','))) AS x;
```

But I can't figure out how to apply this logic to insertions.

What I want is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t00(
  userid int8 PRIMARY KEY,
  a      int8,
  b      varchar);

INSERT  INTO t00 (userid,a,b)  VALUES (0,1,'fish,sheep,dove');

INSERT  INTO t00 (userid,a,b)  VALUES (0,1,',fish,eagle')
  ON CONFLICT (userid)
  DO UPDATE SET
    a = EXCLUDED.a,
    b = SELECT string_agg(unnest, ',') AS x FROM (SELECT DISTINCT unnest(string_to_array(t00.b || EXCLUDED.b, ','))) AS x;
```

How can I achieve something like that?

Comment: Storing comma separated values in a relational database is a very bad idea.

Comment: If you want to denormalize, then at least use an array, rather than an extremely error prone comma separated list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing comma separated values is a huge mistake to begin with. But if you really want to make your life harder than it needs to be, you might want to create a function that merges two comma separated lists:

```
create function merge_lists(p_one text, p_two text)
  returns text
as
$$
  select string_agg(item, ',')
  from (
    select e.item
    from unnest(string_to_array(p_one, ',')) as e(item)
    where e.item <> '' --< necessary because of the leading , in your data
    union 
    select t.item
    from unnest(string_to_array(p_two, ',')) t(item)
    where t.item <> ''
  ) t;
$$
language sql;
```

If you are using Postgres 14 or later, `unnest(string_to_array(..., ','))` can be replace with `string_to_table(..., ',')`

Then your INSERT statement gets a bit simpler:

```
INSERT  INTO t00 (userid,a,b)  VALUES (0,1,',fish,eagle')
  ON CONFLICT (userid)
  DO UPDATE SET
    a = EXCLUDED.a,
    b = merge_lists(excluded.b, t00.b);
```

Comment: Probably something like `create function merge_lists(p_one anyarray, p_two anyarray)` would be more general....

Comment: @Abelisto: yes, but that would require to change the really bad model using a CSV value to a less bad model using an array

Comment: This is nice, thanks. When both input strings are the empty string, the resulting string is `NULL`. How can I make it be the empty string instead?

Answer (score 2):

I think I was only missing parentheses around the `SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT  INTO t00 (userid,a,b)  VALUES (0,1,',fish,eagle')
  ON CONFLICT (userid)
  DO UPDATE SET
    a = EXCLUDED.a,
    b = (SELECT string_agg(unnest, ',') AS x FROM (SELECT DISTINCT unnest(string_to_array(t00.b || EXCLUDED.b, ','))) AS x);
```